# Xcode command line build failed

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3, xcode8, ionic-native

I am using ionic 3 for IOS app development while trying build on command line am getting following error.I am new to MAC(IOS development)

ionic version:3
Xcode version :8.2.1

```
The following build commands failed:
    CompileC /Users/themesoft/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-bkemlyweisesndehdvyeqrojralm/Build/Intermediates/MyApp.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/MyApp.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/IONAssetHandler.o MyApp/Plugins/cordova-plugin-ionic-webview/IONAssetHandler.m normal x86_64 objective-c com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler
(1 failure)
CordovaError: Promise rejected with non-error: 'Error code 65 for command: xcodebuild with args: -xcconfig,/Users/themesoft/Desktop/myapp/platforms/ios/cordova/build-debug.xcconfig,-workspace,MyApp.xcworkspace,-scheme,MyApp,-configuration,Debug,-sdk,iphonesimulator,-destination,platform=iOS Simulator,name=iPhone SE,build,CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR=/Users/themesoft/Desktop/myapp/platforms/ios/build/emulator,SHARED_PRECOMPS_DIR=/Users/themesoft/Desktop/myapp/platforms/ios/build/sharedpch'
    at cli.catch.err (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/bin/cordova:30:15)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)
[ERROR] An error occurred while running subprocess cordova.

    cordova run ios exited with exit code 1.
```

Comment: I am also getting the same error, did you find the solution?

Comment: Yes uninstall xcode and reinstall fixed the error